# How can I use the last result from a scala map as input to the next function?

Tags: scala

I'm working through some project euler questions to practice my scala. For problem 7 I have to find the 10001st prime. I have a working solution, but dont feel its as functional as it could be.

```
  def first_n_primes(n: Long) : List[Long] = {
    var last_prime = 1L
    (1L to n).map(x => {last_prime = get_next_prime(x, last_prime); last_prime}).toList
  }
```

Specifically,  I feel there might be a way to get rid of the var last_prime, but I dont know how to use the result of the nth map evaluation as the input to the n+1 evaluation. How can I do this more functionally?

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Is there a way to use result of map or how to solve the problem 7?

Comment: I've solved problem 7. get_next prime starts from the last prime so its not rediscovering old primes - I just want to know if theres a better way to get the result from the nth evalauation to be an input to the n+1 evaluation.

Comment: You can use `scan,scanLeft,fold,foldLeft,reduce, reduceLeft` higher order function for getting the result from nth evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `scanLeft`:

```
(1l to n).scanLeft(1) { case (x, last) => get_next_prime(x, last) }
```

Or just `(1l to n).scanLeft(1)(get_next_prime)`

Note however that this is not a very good algorithm looking for the primes, because there is a lot of repetitive work that could be saved (to find the next prime, you need to re-discover all the previous ones).

This sort of task is better done in scala with recursive streams:

```
lazy val primes: Stream[Long] = 2 #:: Stream.iterate(3l)(_+1).filter { n => 
  val stop = math.sqrt(n)
  primes.takeWhile { _ <= stop }.forall { k => n % k != 0 }
}
primes.take(n).toList
```

Comment: scanLeft is perfect! Thankyou! The one change I made is last is actually the first parameter as it holds the result of the previous operation. So I changed the signature of get_next_prime to reflect this. The use of scanleft lets me avoid recalculating previous primes because now I always start from the last prime calculated.

Comment: It's not just where you _start_ that matters. When you check whether a given number is prime, you don't have to try to divide it by every smaller number, it is enough to verify only primes.